# Filter by Year in DAX query - Tabular Cube

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

This seems like an easy one to solve, but I haven't been able to do it and haven't found a similar question.

I'm using openquery to select data from a tabular cube. I want to filter by year.

```
 DECLARE @GetData VARCHAR(MAX)
,@Customer AS varchar(4) = '6300'

SELECT @GetData = 

'SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery (ASLS,
''
EVALUATE 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS
(
Customer[CustomerNbr],
FILTER(VALUES(Date[Year]), Date[Year] = 2019), 
FILTER(VALUES(Customer[CustomerNbr]), Customer[CustomerNbr] = "' + @Customer +'"),
"TotalSales", [TotalSales]
)'')'


EXEC(@GetData)
```

This is the error I get:

OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "ASLS" returned message "Query (6, 19) The syntax for '[Year]' is incorrect.

It works with just the customer filter, but not with year. Eventually, I'll want multiple years, which I believe is done with "AND", but I can get even one year.

I tried to wrap the year using single & double quotes, brackets, etc., but still looking for an answer or the next step to research.

TIA

EDIT: Could my errors be due to the table named "Date", which is the name of a function?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. I added `'Date'[YearValue]` (note single quotes around table name). This seems to work. I think it's because this is a reserved word.

EDIT: In the open query example, the syntax is

```
''''Date''''[YearValue],
```